# Laravel 5.1 | Post requests don't work without the "/public" in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, post, request

As the title says,

Post requests don't work without the "/public" in the URL in **Laravel 5.1**

For example, in the **login form** if the action url is

```
/auth/login
```

it does not work and redirects me to the login page again after submitting it, but if I change the action url to

```
/public/auth/login
```

it works correctly.
The same for other forms.

Here is my .htaccess file located in the laravel root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the .htaccess file located in the public folder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Btw, the app is published on a Godaddy shared hosting account.
This problem does not exist on the local server (**wamp**)

How to solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to serve your application? (Apache, nginx, `./artisan serve`. I bet that you didn't add `public` onto the end of your vhost. Also why change `server.php` to `index.php`?

Comment: The app is published on a Godaddy shared hosting account.
I read an article that said that the server.php file needs to be renamed to index.php. Anyway I renamed it back to server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed because of using the url() method.

For example in the login.blade.php file => the login form
When I changed this

```
action="{{url('auth/login')}}"
```

to this

```
action="{{action('Auth\AuthController@postLogin')}}"
```

And changed the route name of the login action to

```
/login
```

instead of

```
/auth/login
```

It worked.
I doubt the reason may be that the form is submitting to a url which is the same as the url of the current page containing the form.